# Proof of a lemma about PPE

Tags: game-theory, repeated-games

[image: Definition if PPE]

[image: Proof of Lemma]
[image]
[image]

Dear all, I am studying the repeated game with imperfect monitoring. I have so many questions about the proof of lemma 3.6 in slide 22. First of all, why we can write
$$
P_{\widehat{\sigma}_{i}, \sigma_{-i}}\left(A_{t}=\text{a} \mid H_{t}=h_{t}\right) =\widehat{\sigma}_{i}\left(h_{t} ; \text{a}_{i}\right) \sigma_{-i}\left(h_{t}, \text{a}_{-i}\right)
=P_{\sigma}\left(A_{t}=\text{a} \mid H_{t}=h_{t}\right)
$$
in the equation (1) of the slide 22? I have try to rewrite the left-hand side of equation (1) as $$P_{\widehat{\sigma}_{i}, \sigma_{-i}}\left(A_{t}=\text{a} \mid H_{t}=h_{t}\right)=\dfrac{P_{\hat{\sigma}, \sigma_{-i}}(A_t = \text{a}_{i}, H_t=h_t)}{P_{\hat{\sigma}, \sigma_{-i}}(H_t=h_t)}$$, and I also rewrite the right-hand side of the equation (1) as \begin{align*}
\widehat{\sigma}_{i}\left(h_{t} ; \text{a}_{i}\right) \sigma_{-i}\left(h_{t}, \text{a}_{-i}\right)&=P_{\sigma}(A^t_i = \text{a}_{i}\mid H_t=h_t)P_{\sigma}(A^t_i = \text{a}_{-i}\mid H_t=h_t)\\
&=\dfrac{P_{\sigma}(A^t_i = \text{a}_{i}, H_t=h_t)}{P_{\sigma}(H_t=h_t)}\dfrac{P_{\sigma}(A^t_i = \text{a}_{-i}, H_t=h_t)}{{P_{\sigma}(H_t=h_t)}}.
\end{align*}
Then I still didn't see why the equality in the equation (1) holds.

Finally, I also confuse about each equality in the second bullet of the slide 23. I will really appreciate if anyone can explain this.

Many thanks.

Comment: $\sigma_{-i}(h_t,a_{-i})$ is not what you have written, but is the probability of getting to the joint state $h_t,a_{-i}$ under $\sigma_{-i}$.

Comment: Do you have a page specifying the mathematical and economic meaning of each symbol?